# lucene wikipedia querying

Tags: lucene, tokenize

I'm using lucene to query from wiki dump and get the categories out. So, I get the relevant documents and for every document, I call the below function.

```
static List<String> getCategories(Document document) throws IOException
{
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = document.get("text");
    WikipediaTokenizer tf = new WikipediaTokenizer(new StringReader(text));

    CharTermAttribute termAtt = tf.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    TypeAttribute typeAtt = tf.addAttribute(TypeAttribute.class);

    while (tf.incrementToken())
    {
        String tokText = termAtt.toString();
        if (typeAtt.type().equals(WikipediaTokenizer.CATEGORY) == true)
        {
            categories.add(tokText);
        }
    }

    return categories;
}
```

but it throws the following error at the while statement.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(WikipediaTokenizerImpl.java:574)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(WikipediaTokenizerImpl.java:781)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizer.incrementToken(WikipediaTokenizer.java:200)
    at SearchIndex.getCategories(SearchIndex.java:82)
    at SearchIndex.main(SearchIndex.java:54)
```

I looked at zzRefill() function but it I'm not able to understand it. Is this a known bug or something? I don't know what am I doing wrong. The lucene guys says that the whole wikipediaTokenizer section is in beta and maybe be subject to changes. I was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: A `NullPointer` exception occurs when an object variable is dereferenced (as in `SearchIndex.getCategories`), but the object variable doesn't actually contain an object (`new` was not called).  It looks like it's happening at `tf.IncrementToken()` in the `while` loop condition.

Comment: but where do I put in the new? I'm really sorry but I have hardly programmed in java... I'm writing a quick hacky program to get the job done somehow...

Comment: Is `getCategories` your code?  It's happening in Lucene, so without the source code, I don't know how this can be troubleshooted.

Comment: yes, I'm borrowing the relevant parts from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924543/example-using-wikipediatokenizer-in-lucene

Comment: yes, I'm afraid that's the case. The documentation says that wikipedia tokenizer (which I'm using) is subject to drastic changes and may break ocasionally. I'll try my luck in the mailing lists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding tf.reset() before calling the while loop