# WikipediaTokenizer Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, wiki, tokenize, wikipedia

I try to parse Wikipedia markup with Lucene and found this little project:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-wikipedia/org/apache/lucene/wikipedia/analysis/WikipediaTokenizer.html

(was not able to retrieve a proper website, sorry)

Below is a shorter version of a code example that circulates somehow around this library. When running it, I get a non-null WikipediaTokenizer, but I get a null pointer exception as soon as I execute incrementToken(). Any ideas?

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Token;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizer;

import java.io.StringReader;

public class WikipediaTokenizerTest {
  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WikipediaTokenizerTest.class);
  protected static final String LINK_PHRASES = "click [[link here again]] click     [http://lucene.apache.org here again] [[Category:a b c d]]";

public WikipediaTokenizer testSimple() throws Exception {
    String text = "This is a [[Category:foo]]";
    return new WikipediaTokenizer(new StringReader(text));
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    WikipediaTokenizerTest wtt = new WikipediaTokenizerTest();

    try {
        WikipediaTokenizer x = wtt.testSimple();

        logger.info(x.hasAttributes());

        while (x.incrementToken() == true) {
            logger.info("Token found!");
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception while tokenizing Wiki Text: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I use the following dependencies for Maven (pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-wikipedia</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated! If someone has a better library or solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix-and-match your lucene versions.  You are using version 4.2.1.  It is not compatible with either version 3.1.0 or 3.0.3.  You need to remove those dependencies.

`WikipediaTokenizer` is included in analyzers-common.

---

Also, you are not fulfilling the contract required by `TokenStream`.  See the [`TokenStream` documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html) where where the workflow of the TokenStream API is described.  In particular, before ever calling `incrementToken()`, you must call `reset()`.  You should really also `end()` and `close()` it.

```
WikipediaTokenizer x = wtt.testSimple();
logger.info(x.hasAttributes());
x.reset();
while (x.incrementToken() == true) {
    logger.info("Token found!");
}
x.end();
x.close();
```

Comment: And you are definitely getting a `NullPointerException`, not, say, an `IllegalStateException`?  I definitely see why you could get an `IllegalStateException`, but having run this code, I'm not seeing anything that causes a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(WikipediaTokenizerImpl.java:574) at org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(WikipediaTokenizerImpl.java:781) at org.apache.lucene.analysis.wikipedia.WikipediaTokenizer.incrementToken(WikipediaTokenizer.java:200) ... and after that pointing to that while loop

Comment: Looks like it might be caused by the same issues I would have expected to throw an `IllegalStateException`.  I've added some information to my answer.

Comment: How do I actually access the attributes (i.e. if i want to simply output the text and filter out all tokens that are links)?            The example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924543/example-using-wikipediatokenizer-in-lucene does not address the modifications that happend in lucene 4 (I cannot find TermAttribute any more)